# Convert Flex build ant target into gradle. What is required to run flex build in gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I am working on gradle script.I don't have much idea about flex builds.I am trying to convert one ant target to gradle but due to little knowledge about flex I am not sure how I could achieve this? This ant target is working fine in linux platform but gradle is not working

Ant Target

```
<target name="adminClient">
<if name="build.flash" value="true">
<echo message="mxmlc.exe ${mxmlc.exe}"/>
<echo message="Building AdminClient.swf"/>
<exec executable="${mxmlc.exe}" dir="${basedir}" failonerror="true">
<arg line="'${adminClient.src.module}'"/>
<arg line="-load-config='${build.dir}/ozswfconfig.xml'"/>
<arg line="-load-config+='${build.dir}/license.xml'"/>
<arg line="-output '${package.dir}/AdminClient.swf'"/>
<arg line="-library-path+='${external.lib.dir}/PureMVC_AS3_MultiCore_1_0_4.swc'"/>
<arg line="-library-path+='${flexCommon.lib}'"/>
<arg line="-source-path '${adminClient.src.dir}'"/>
</exec>
<!--  build each tab separatley for new ui  -->
<exec executable="${mxmlc.exe}" dir="${basedir}" failonerror="true">
<arg line="'${adminClient.src.dir}/ConfigurationApp.mxml'"/>
<arg line="-load-config='${build.dir}/ozswfconfig.xml'"/>
<arg line="-load-config+='${build.dir}/license.xml'"/>
<arg line="-output '${package.dir}/ConfigurationApp.swf'"/>
<arg line="-library-path+='${external.lib.dir}/PureMVC_AS3_MultiCore_1_0_4.swc'"/>
<arg line="-library-path+='${flexCommon.lib}'"/>
<arg line="-source-path '${adminClient.src.dir}'"/>
<exec executable="${mxmlc.exe}" dir="${basedir}" failonerror="true">
<arg line="'${adminClient.src.dir}/LargeResultsApp.mxml'"/>
<arg line="-load-config='${build.dir}/ozswfconfig.xml'"/>
<arg line="-load-config+='${build.dir}/license.xml'"/>
<arg line="-output '${package.dir}/LargeResultsApp.swf'"/>
<arg line="-library-path+='${external.lib.dir}/PureMVC_AS3_MultiCore_1_0_4.swc'"/>
<arg line="-library-path+='${flexCommon.lib}'"/>
<arg line="-source-path '${adminClient.src.dir}'"/>
</exec>
</if>
</target>
```

I tried in gradle script in below manner but it is not working

```
task adminClient(dependsOn: prepConfigs) {
    println "mxmlc.exe ${mxmlcexe}"
    exec {
        workingDir = file("${projectDir}")
        executable "${mxmlcexe}"
        args ["${adminClientsrcModule}", "-load-config='${Folderdir}/ozswfconfig.xml", "-load-config+='${Folderdir}/license.xml", "-output '${packageDir}/AdminClient.swf", "-library-path+='${externallibDir}/PureMVC_AS3_MultiCore_1_0_4.swc", "-library-path+='${flexCommonLib}", "-source-path '${adminClientsrcDir}"]
   }
    exec {
        workingDir = file("${projectDir}")
        executable "${mxmlcexe}"
        args "${adminClientsrcDir}/ConfigurationApp.mxml", "-load-config='${Folderdir}/ozswfconfig.xml", "-load-config+='${Folderdir}/license.xml", "-output '${packageDir}/ConfigurationApp.swf", "-library-path+='${externallibDir}/PureMVC_AS3_MultiCore_1_0_4.swc", "-library-path+='${flexCommonLib}", "-source-path '${adminClientsrcDir}"
   exec {
        workingDir = file("${projectDir}")
        executable "${mxmlc.exe}"
        args "${adminClientsrcDir}/LargeResultsApp.mxml", "-load-config='${Folderdir}/ozswfconfig.xml", "-load-config+='${Folderdir}/license.xml", "-output '${packageDir}/LargeResultsApp.swf", "-library-path+='${externallibDir}/PureMVC_AS3_MultiCore_1_0_4.swc", "-library-path+='${flexCommonLib}", "-source-path '${adminClientsrcDir}"
   }

  }
```

Can someone let me know if I need to use any plugin to build flex or how I could convert this ant target into gradle in correct manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mechanical translation to Gradle, using the implicit Ant Builder, looks like this:

```
task adminClient() << {
    // look for -Dbuild.flash on command-line
    def buildFlash = ant.properties['build.flash']

    if (buildFlash) {
        ant.echo(message: "Building AdminClient.swf")

        ant.exec(executable: "{mxmlc.exe}", dir: "${basedir}", failonerror: "true") {
            arg(line: " '${adminClient.src.module}'")
            arg(line: " -load-config='${build.dir}/ozswfconfig.xml'")
            arg(line: " -load-config+='${build.dir}/license.xml'")
            arg(line: " -output '${package.dir}/AdminClient.swf'")
            arg(line: " -library-path+='${external.lib.dir}/PureMVC_AS3_MultiCore_1_0_4.swc'")
            arg(line: " -library-path+='${flexCommon.lib}'")
            arg(line: " -source-path '${adminClient.src.dir}'")
        }
    } else {
        // build each tab separatley for new ui 
        ant.exec(executable: "${mxmlc.exe}", dir: "${basedir}", failonerror: "true") {
            arg(line: " '${adminClient.src.dir}/ConfigurationApp.mxml'")
            arg(line: " -load-config='${build.dir}/ozswfconfig.xml'")
            arg(line: " -load-config+='${build.dir}/license.xml'")
            arg(line: " -output '${package.dir}/ConfigurationApp.swf'")
            arg(line: " -library-path+='${external.lib.dir}/PureMVC_AS3_MultiCore_1_0_4.swc'")
            arg(line: " -library-path+='${flexCommon.lib}'")
            arg(line: " -source-path '${adminClient.src.dir}'")
        }

        ant.exec(executable: "${mxmlc.exe}", dir: "${basedir}", failonerror: "true") {
            arg(line: "'${adminClient.src.dir}/LargeResultsApp.mxml'")
            arg(line: " -load-config='${build.dir}/ozswfconfig.xml'")
            arg(line: " -load-config+='${build.dir}/license.xml'")
            arg(line: " -output '${package.dir}/LargeResultsApp.swf'")
            arg(line: " -library-path+='${external.lib.dir}/PureMVC_AS3_MultiCore_1_0_4.swc'")
            arg(line: " -library-path+='${flexCommon.lib}'")
            arg(line: " -source-path '${adminClient.src.dir}'")
        }
     }
 }
```

}

Something like this should work, so long as the various variables (e.g. `${build.dir}`, `${flexCommon.lib}`) are sorted out. I have illustrated one example with `build.flash` as the beginning.

Comment: I am getting this error A problem occurred evaluating root project 'adminclient'.
> Could not find property 'arg' on task ':adminClient'

Comment: Apologies... I have corrected "arg.line(" to be "arg(line:"